# Add image with scale + rotation to video overlay with FFMPEG?

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, rotation, overlay

I want to add overlay images to videos with params

1: w:h --> is width and height of image on the video

2: r --> Radian is rotation of images

3: center (x,y) --> is center point of image in the video

This is my FFMPEG command :

> `-i video.mp4 -i image.png filter_complex [1:v]scale=w:h[scale];[scale]rotate=r:ow=iw:oh=ih[rotate];[0:v][rotate]overlay=x-(w/2):y-(h/2)`

But the result not correct. It's Only work with scale=1 and rotate=0 radian

How can i do this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
[1:v]scale=w:h,pad=iw+4:ih+4:black@0[scale];[scale]rotate=r:ow='rotw(r)':oh='roth(r)'[rotate]
```

A bit of transparent padding is added to the image before rotation. This is because the rotate filter will fill the gaps in the canvas with the input's border pixel color. Also, the output size has to be adjusted to accommodate the whole image after rotation. See the [docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate) for the rotate filter.

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg command to rotate, scale, overlay and set image duration on a video

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i inputImg.png -filter_complex \"[1:v] rotate=90:c=none:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih) [rotate];[rotate]scale=100:-1[scale];[0:v][scale] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,2)'[out]\" -map [out] -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```